# my three js keyboard controls dont work correctly when i turn my camera around 180 degrees

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, game-physics, game-development

i've implemented a threejs keyboard control function that works fine as long as the camera is facing north, east or west direction, when it turns south, south-east, or south-west the controls reverse themselves

```js
    if(controls["KeyW"]){ // w
      camera.position.x -= Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
      camera.position.z -= -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
    }
    if(controls["KeyS"]){ // s
      camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
      camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
    }
    if(controls["KeyA"]){ // a
      camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2) * player.speed;
      camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2) * player.speed;
    }
    if(controls["KeyD"]){ // d
      camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI / 2) * player.speed;
      camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI / 2) * player.speed;
    }
    if(controls["Space"]) { // space
      if(player.jumps) return false;
      player.jumps = true;
      player.velocity = -player.jumpHeight;
    }
  }
```

to better help you understand the problem i've been facing here's a [link](https://suspicious-nobel-755a5e.netlify.app/) to my website, my guess is that the sin and cos revserse their values after a 180 rotation

Comment: throw away Euler angles and use [4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) instead... otherwise you will always keep having bugs like this because of the math singularities involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the mistake i was making was that i was using pointer controls for mouse navigation and keyboard triggers to move around, digged the docs a little and realised that i could use built in functions of PointerLockControls called `moveForward` and `moveRight`

```js
  const mouseControls = new PointerLockControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  document.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    mouseControls.lock()
  }, false)


  const keysDown: any = {
    "KeyW": 0,
    "KeyA": 0,
    "KeyS": 0,
    "KeyD": 0,
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", ({ code }) => {
    keysDown[code] = 1 
  })
  document.addEventListener("keyup", ({ code }) => {
    keysDown[code] = 0
  })

  function updateControls() {
    const forwardDirection = keysDown["KeyW"] - keysDown["KeyS"];
    const rightDirection = keysDown["KeyD"] - keysDown["KeyA"];
    mouseControls.moveForward(forwardDirection * player.speed)
    mouseControls.moveRight(rightDirection * player.speed)
  }

  ////////main animation function
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    updateControls();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  };

  animate();
```